# tkinter: How can I get the users choice of filetype in the asksaveasfilename-dialog?

Tags: python, tkinter

currently, I'm programming a GUI, which should allow the user to save a file and select the filetype (lets say: jpg, bmp). I'm using tkinter with Python 3.4.

Unfortunately, I am unable figure out, which filetype the user has selected: I'm using the asksaveasfilename-dialog and all I can get is the path:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes = [('Bitmap', '.bmp'),('jpg', '.jpg')])
```

I can try to extract the extension from the path, but that can leed to unexpected behaviour:

1. if the user doesn't provide the extension in the filename but selects the filetype, "path" doesn't contain any extension
2. if the user first decides to use the filename "example.bmp" but afterwards selects jpg as filetype, the extension is not updatet (as it normally is in window). So "path" will still be: C:\ ... \example.bmp

Is there a way to get the filetype, that the user selected?
Is there any other way around?

Comment: I think your only recourse is to use something like [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html?highlight=splitext#os.path.splitext) on the value returned.

Comment: That is, what I'm doing at the moment. But as mentioned in example 2, the extension could be .bmp although the user selected png as filetype.

 ---- so when i use os.path.splittext(), the file would be saved as bmp, although the user explicitly selected png as filetype.

Comment: The file type the user selects only affects what the user sees in the file list shown in dialog box. What is returned is what the user wants — so using `splitext()` will be correct.

Comment: To check file type regerdless of extensions, you need to check file magic number (i.e. [file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)). There are 3th party modules in python for this. If you are concerned only with few files, than checking the numbers is relatively easy.

Comment: @martineau: the user wants windows-like behaviour, which tkinter unfortunately doesn't provide. Yes, In windows, the filetype does affekt, what the user sees in the save-as dialogbox but furthermore, it affects the filetype directly. E.g. in Ms Paint: I can save an image in the bmp-format under the filename example.jpg. The result is a file with an "incorrect" extension, but that is exactly how it should be under windows.

Comment: @Marcin: thank you --  but I'm talking about saving files, not reading them. So, there is no magic number that could be evaluated.

Comment: You have a user who wants to give image files the wrong extension? Interesting. I'm afraid `asksaveasfilename` was designed to get the file's name only. You'll likely have to create your own dialog box to do what you want via tkinter. Another possibility would be to use the common dialogs built-in to Windows via the ctypes or win32 modules.

Comment: Thank you. I will try the common dialogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I struggle with the same problem of automatically updating the extension, I stumbled over your question. Apparently you can try that with [addins](https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/thespatialextent):

```
pythonaddins.SaveDialog = saveFileDialog
```

This one is almost identical to OpenDialog except that instead of filtering files, we have the ability to automatically append a particular extension to the user's input. It's also possible to pass in a tupled list of filetype descriptions and extension which would then populate the Save As Filetype Dropdown, but again the only thing that is doing is filtering the files displayed. It's actually the FileExtension parameter that is appending the extension to the return value.