# Getting the selected extension from Tkinter.asksaveasfilename dialog?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to implement a dialog box in a GUI, and would like to have the selected extension appended to the end of the typed in file name:

[image: SaveAs Dialog]

and I have come across these following threads:

[tkinter: How can I get the users choice of filetype in the asksaveasfilename-dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228956/tkinter-how-can-i-get-the-users-choice-of-filetype-in-the-asksaveasfilename-dia)
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2002-June/173039.html

Which seems to imply that the `asksaveasfilename` tool from tkinter does not currently have this function.

Does anyone have a good solution for this? For example something similar to:

```
filename = asksaveasfilename(
            filetypes=[('XLS File', '*.xls'), ('CSV File', '*.csv')],
            appendExt=True)
```

or do I have to write my own just for this little missing function?

Note: This was working perfectly when I ran the code in Ubuntu, but unfortunately not in Windows 10.

Comment: What do you mean by "This was working perfectly when I ran the code in Ubuntu"?  How could it since `asksaveasfilename()` has no `appendExt` keyword argument?

Comment: @martineau Yes that 'appendExt' part was my added fantasy. The line I had in my code had everything before it, and when the code was executed in Ubuntu, the returned 'filename' has the extension selected in the dialog automatically appended to it. Unfortunately this is not the case when I execute the code in Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You can take this using

```
filename = asksaveasfilename(
    filetypes=[
        ('XLS File', '*.xls'), 
        ('CSV File', '*.csv')],
    defaultextension=[
        ('XLS File', '*.xls'), 
        ('CSV File', '*.csv')])
```

It works for me .-.